# how to POST an empty file with name set by javascript(not ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Name a file that doesn't exists and sent it by POST.
I need to realize it automatically instead of upload and click submit.
Here is what I want:
[image]
I achieved it by using FormData through AJAX but found my circumstance doesn't allow ajax request.
It needs standard HTTP POST request.
Is there a way to post a file that doesn't exist with the name customized?

**AJAX** would be intercepted by server. I need it to test an xss attack.

Comment: @StanimirStoyanov Are there any answers there that don't use AJAX?

Comment: Why can't you use AJAX? It looks just like an ordinary POST request.

Comment: Why is AJAX not possible? Is it because you are trying to post on a cross-origin domain?

Comment: I doubt this can be done only using a form and default browser submit process. You can't programmatically bind a file to an input for obvious security reasons

Comment: @Barmar actually no, initially I though that he can't use jQuery, so XMLHttpRequest would be the alternative. I want to ask the same question - why AJAX can't be used?

Comment: @Barmar AJAX would be intercepted by server. I need it to test an xss attack.

Comment: Try using Postman to forge the attack then. It will be easier and it can be automated if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Or  do it using server side script and cURL if all you are doing is testing

Comment: @yaochiqkl Cross-origin AJAX is not blocked by the server. It's the client that intercepts the response.